# Limit scroll to element jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll, limit

My goal is to have a social share bar scroll with the page from one element to another. You can see my progress here http://ossian.statenews.com/~matt/statenews-redesign/docs/article.html. Right now the element scrolls all the way to the bottom, where as I want to to scroll to the top of "related stories". Here is my jQuery:........

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $sidebar   = $("#sharebox"),
 $window    = $(window),
 offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
 topPadding = 50;

 $window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding  
        });
    } else {
    $sidebar.stop().animate({
    marginTop: 0
    });
    }
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement only check the `window` scrolltop, you should check `.related-stories` too.

```
if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top && $window.scrollTop() < $('.related-storie').scrollTop()) {
    $sidebar.stop().animate({
        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding  
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me an example of how I would include this?

Answer (score 0):

it will be much better user experience if you use the fixed position of your block, like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $sidebar   = $("#sharebox"),
    $window    = $(window),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    topPadding = 50,
    $leadStory  = $('.leadstory');
    $relatedStories  = $('.related-stories');

    $sidebar.css({
        position : 'fixed',
        'margin-left' : 0,
        left : offset.left,
        top : offset.top
    });

    var criteria = $relatedStories.offset().top - $sidebar.height();
    $window.scroll(function() {
        if ($window.scrollTop() > criteria) {
            $sidebar.css({
                top : offset.top - ($window.scrollTop() - criteria)
            });
        } else {
            $sidebar.css({
                top : offset.top
            });
        }
    });
});
```

check out the new version above

Comment: I applied this and it seems to disappear when I scroll past it, then reappear when I scroll back to the top.

Comment: check out the new version above

Comment: hmm, that appeared to have just made the element fixed, not scroll with the page.

Comment: yes the page scroll under that element until it reaches the related-stories block.